Adding zsh autocomplete suggestion to my bash script
Let's say I have bash script named "player", I want to get autosuggestions when using player script with --file flag in my zsh shell:
player --file ...

Correct values could be obtained with ls /path/to/dir/never/changes. How can I give user of player script dynamic (files will be added to dir mentioned above) auto suggestions inside zsh shell (I don't use bash so only concerned about zsh).
I couldn't find any questions here that was about developing app/script/program autocompletion.
